# How can I plot evenly spaced values on the y axis using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was trying to plot pitches in matlplotlib while labeling yaxis frequency with musical note name, but having trouble in spacing evenly values in yaxis.

Here is an example of code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

note_frequency = []
for i in range(60):
    note_frequency.append(
        55 * 2**(i/12)
    )

note_name = [
    'A1', 'A#1', 'B1', 'C2', 'C#2', 'D2', 'D#2', 'E2', 'F2', 'F#2', 'G2', 'G#2',
    'A2', 'A#2', 'B2', 'C3', 'C#3', 'D3', 'D#3', 'E3', 'F3', 'F#3', 'G3', 'G#3',
    'A3', 'A#3', 'B3', 'C4', 'C#4', 'D4', 'D#4', 'E4', 'F4', 'F#4', 'G4', 'G#4',
    'A4', 'A#4', 'B4', 'C5', 'C#5', 'D5', 'D#5', 'E5', 'F5', 'F#5', 'G5', 'G#5',
    'A5', 'A#5', 'B5', 'C6', 'C#6', 'D6', 'D#6', 'E6', 'F6', 'F#6', 'G6', 'G#6',
]

a = np.arange(60)
test_data = [120, 500, 120, 440, 860, 550, 80, 160, 250, 300, 600, 589, 456, 151, 987, 1600]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.yaxis.set_ticks(note_frequency)
ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels(note_name)
ax.plot(test_data)
plt.show()
```

---

Plot for example in question.
[image]

Comment: It is not clear what your question is. You are setting your y axis ticks at locations that are calculated with an exponential - `...2**(i/12)...` - they cannot be *evenly* spaced.

Comment: It is an general equation for calculating the frequency of musical tone. More can be found in [link](http://techlib.com/reference/musical_note_frequencies.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the log of the values:

```
ax.yaxis.set_ticks(np.log2(note_frequency), note_name)
ax.plot(np.log2(test_data))
```

Or:

```
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks(note_frequency, note_name)
ax.plot(test_data)
```

Or:

```
ax.semilogy(test_data,base=2)
ax.yaxis.set_ticks(note_frequency, note_name)
```

(thanks @wwmi)

Output:

[image]

Comment: Also `ax.semilogy(test_data,base=2)`; then set the ticks and labels.

Comment: @wwii yes, good alternative! Btw, I chose a base 2 as it's more logical in the context of music but any base would give the same output ;)

Comment: Seems like you can do things many different ways *in* Matplolib.